# Gray-level co-occurrence matrix feature computation

Tags: python, performance, image, numpy, signal-processing

I have many images and want to compute the GLCM properties for every image. Below my code that runs many hours to complete the task:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops

ANGLES = [0., np.pi/4., np.pi/2., 3.*np.pi/4.]
DISTANCES = [1,2]
properties = ["correlation", "contrast", "homogeneity", "energy"]
n_img = 1000

I = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(n_img, 100, 100))

stats = []
for k in range(n_img):
    glcm = greycomatrix(I[k], distances=DISTANCES, angles=ANGLES, levels=256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
    prop = [np.mean(greycoprops(glcm, properties[i])) for i in range(len(properties))]
    stats.append(prop)
stats = np.array(stats)
```

This code is a real bottleneck. How can parallelize the task? Are there other ways to speed up the code?

Comment: related: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3413 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551249/implementing-glcm-texture-feature-with-scikit-image-and-python

Comment: Since the bottleneck clearly is the usage of the `greycomatrix` and `greycoprops`, I'm inclined to believe the question really is "How can I parallelize the task", which falls out of scope for this site.

Comment: @IEatBagels Why?